# How would medieval civilizations be changed if lands were seas and seas were lands?

Tags: environment, geography, earth, civilization

If we lived on Earth, but with land and sea swapped, how would this affect civilizations on Earth?

This would include a total topographic inversion of Earth, so

- The Mariana Trench would become the tallest mountain range on Earth
- Mount Everest would become the deepest part of the oceans
- Australia would become the largest lake/smallest ocean
- etc.

Now, the world did not start with a giant Pangaea-shaped ocean, but there have been some minor tectonic shifts causing the formation of the mountain ranges, and making Mount Everest the deepest part of the oceans.

In this backwards world, how would the rise of medieval civilization be affected? Specifically, I am curious about

- How the size and location of civilizations would be affected
- If relations between different countries would change (more peaceful/more aggressive).
- Would populations be more spread out
- Would sea travel still be a valid option
- Would the availability of fresh water cause major issues
- How much of the land would not host livable conditions for civilization?

We can ignore how the world is scientifically possible (since they continents would break up very quickly) I'm just wondering how civilizations would have adapted due to all of the extra land and very limited water.

Comment: Welcome to the site Flotolk.  Conceptually I like this questions but it is WAY to broad at the moment.  Can you focus this a little, maybe ask about a particular aspect?

Comment: Would it start out that way, or is there some sort of cataclysmic event going on that completely redefines the topography of the planet? Because the former probably wouldn't change much, while the latter would probably kill everything.

Comment: Honestly I have no clue what the actual question is. Are you searching for something among the lines of _"There's too much land / not enough water, we need to find water sources"_?.

Comment: Likely, life would be concentrated around the lakes of the world and only fliers would have (relatively) easy access to large potions of the world, due to having some massive mountains all over the globe. Ships would likely not be a dominant in transportation (though they should still exist). Humans are very unlikely to have settled far beyond their local lake and might consider the world to be an enclosed space; similar to a "hollow earth" scenario. Australia would be a tiny pond compared to Africa.

Comment: It would look [like this](http://i.imgur.com/EYl1LRw.jpg).

Comment: @Samuel I've explored this land, through the desolate wastes of the pacific desert, across the high Mariana Mountains, across the Suez bridge and through the dark jungles of middle Atlantic. The groves around Florida bay are very nice, I have to say. Hmm, so I wonder what the dead sea area would look like... it's the lowest dry land, well below sea level...

Comment: If flipped, inner heat from the earth would be trapped by the continents and they would start to rift and break up.  The land would eventually be subducted into the mantle until the current proportion of land and water was restored.

Comment: @Oldcat Would making the marina trench a massive volcano change this any?

Comment: I think they would all drown. Except the Atlanteans, who would be very confused.

Comment: @Eric, the world was formed like this, so humans began somewhere else

Comment: @Flotolk - not appreciably.  Volcanic areas are in places where continental areas are breaking, high mountains where continents are colliding with ocean plates (Andes/Rockies) or another continent (Himalayas).  But even with far fewer continents on our planet, a single mega continent is too large and breaks up quickly (in geological terms), Your flipped situation would presumably be even more active, triggering mechanisms that eventually would need to reduce the proportion of land mass to something closer to our world

Comment: @James I narrowed the question. this make it any better/

Comment: Samuel, that picture is awesome, Erik, indeed they would. Flotolk, its too bad it got closed but I think as a general rule there would possibly be less habitable areas considering most of the land mass would end up closer to the poles or be so large they'd end up desertic.